# append changing all instances of reference

Tags: python, append

Okay, so I've seen a couple of these topics floating around and the jist of it is that when i

```
list.append([x, y, z])
```

all previous instances of z in the list are changed to the current z. Firstly this is weird because i know people say to do [:] to create a copy rather than a reference, however i have no issue with my variables x and y that change. Further, when i do use z[:] it doesn't help and I think that is because z is a list of lists

for example:

initialization:

```
x = 1

y = 1

z = [[1],[1],[1]]

list = [x,y,z] --> [1,1,[[1],[1],[1]]]
```

as expected.

but, round 2 would go like:

```
x = 2

y = 2

z = [[2],[2],[2]]

list.append([x,y,z]) --> [1,1,[[2],[2],[2]]], [2,2,[[2],[2],[2]]]
```

however what i want is:

```
[1,1,[[1],[1],[1]]], [2,2,[[2],[2],[2]]]
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name as it is a builtin function

Comment: Your code already does what you want it to do.  Did you try running it?  Or are you posting different code from what you're actually running?

Comment: sorry yeah i'm just generically saying list. i'm using different code than what i posted. and yeah I just ran this test code and it works, so that makes the issue ever more confusing. The "z" variable is really 

self.board 

and it saves the current board representation as [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]...etc]

Comment: You need to post code that shows the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is list`[:]` create a shallow copy, if you have nested objects then you need to deepcopy if you want a copy of the list of lists:

```
 from copy import deepcopy
 lst_cp = deepcopy(list_of_lists)
```

Comment: yup this was it! deepcopy fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `z` is a list and lists are mutable. So if you change z it will change anywhere, because python hasn't created a new object for `z`, it has just changed `z`.